# Numerical System

Tags: number-systems

This was my interview question in the question paper.
please help me in finding the answer .

" in a class of 100 students 24 of them are girls and 32 are not. Which numerical system base are we using here? ( Hint: Decimal system base is 10 and binary system base is 2) "

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Assume that any person in the class is either a boy or a girl. Let $b$ be the base. Then we have $b^2=(2b+4)+(3b+2)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since the last digit of the sum is $0$, we must have $4+2=10_b$, since the sum of two digits in any base is always less than $2b$.

---

This assumes that the class contains no transgendered students who're counted as both girls and not-girls (or neither!)